# Rearranging operations to optimize and vectorize nested looping algorithm

Tags: matlab, loops, optimization, vectorization

I have a series of nested loops that works to store data in a cell array. I am trying to find ways to speed up the loop and also help to simplify the readability. I have already optimized the loop a fair bit, but would like to see if I could vectorize it further. My original code looked like this:

```
%% ORIGINAL LOOP
for iA = 1:length(arrA)
  for iB = 1:length(arrB)
    for iC = 1:length(arrC)

      a = arrA(iA);               % depends only on iA
      a_x = AData.x(AData.a==a);
      a_y = AData.y(AData.a==a);

      b = arrB(iB);               % depends only on iB
      b_x = BData.x(BData.b==b);
      b_y = BData.y(BData.b==b);

      c = arrC(iC);               % depends only on iC

      FinalData{iA,iB,iC} = computedata(a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y, c);

    end
  end
end
```

Since the calculations for `a, a_x, a_y` depended only on `iA` I pulled them out of the inner loops, and did similarly for the other variables, which increased performance significantly:

```
%% FASTER LOOP
for iA = 1:length(arrA)
  a = arrA(iA);
  a_x = AData.x(AData.a==a);
  a_y = AData.y(AData.a==a);

  for iB = 1:length(arrB)
    b = arrB(iB);
    b_x = BData.x(BData.b==b);
    b_y = BData.y(BData.b==b);

    for iC = 1:length(arrC)
      c = arrC(iC);

      FinalData{iA,iB,iC} = computedata(a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y, c);

    end
  end
end
```

I am wondering if there yet a better way to speed up this process, perhaps by MATLAB vectorization (elimination of loops altogether).

I also wanted to make it more compact and easier to rearrange the order of the loops if need be, for other functions I plan to design for plotting things in various orders. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless the output of `computedata` is variable size, use `FinalData` as matrix, not cell. Otherwise, no other thing can be improved without the explicit representation of `computedata`

Comment: It is variable size, yes. So there isn't a way to vectorize this operation?

Comment: Vectorizing depends on `computedata`. We don't know what it does.

Comment: One thing you could change is the order of the loops. Optimal looping is in the order in which array elements are stored: `FinalData` is stored with `iA` changing most rapidly, and therefore that loop should be inside; `iC` changes most slowly and should thus be the outer loop. But you need to balance that need with reducing computations, which is the #1 priority.